# How can I use code contracts to check the value of a Lazy<T> without losing the advantages of lazy evaluation?

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-loading, code-contracts

I have code that looks something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly Lazy<string> lazyBar;

    public Foo()
    {
        lazyBar = new Lazy<string>(() => someExpression);
    }

    public string Bar
    {
        get { return lazyBar.Value; }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Contract.Requires(Bar != null); // This evaluates Bar, but all I really require is that WHEN Bar is evaluated, it is not null.

        ...
    }
}
```

Now, every place `DoSomething` is called, we must also prove that `Bar` is not null. But won't checking for this eliminate the benefit of lazy evaluation? Additionally, aren't we supposed to avoid side-effects in our contracts?

Is it possible to prove that `someExpression` will not resolve to null, without evaluating it?

Comment: If you require the Bar property to have a value, aren't you implicitly saying that before `DoSomething` can be called, the lazy-ness have to be resolved to a real value? In other words, I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking how `DoSomething` can require `Bar` to have a value, without resolving the lazy-ness of that property?

Comment: @Lasse: `Bar` must resolve to a real value, but it does not need to already be resolved before the method call. `Contract.Requires(Bar != null)` is just an example, of course this particular `Requires` will evaluate `lazyBar`.

Comment: So then... what is your question exactly? I don't understand what you're asking for here.

Comment: @Lasse: Is it possible to prove that `someExpression` will not resolve to `null`, without evaluating it? I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: No, it is not possible to prove that. This has nothing to do with C# or .NET however, you just can't prove what the outcome of calling code is until you call it, *in the general case*. You can of course make assumptions, or just document that the expression *must* never evaluate to `null`, and then assume it won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code Contracts doesn't have enough insight into `Lazy<T>` in order to make the connection between the original lambda and the result you get back.

What you really want to be able to state (for `Lazy<T>`) is that any contracts that hold about the lambda's return value also hold about the `Value` value, but meta-level contracts like this aren't possible at the moment.

What you could do is move `someExpression` into a method and then have a `Contract.Ensures` that `result != null`. This will then warn you if this condition does not hold. You can then put an `Invariant` onto the result; `lazyBar.Value != null`. This will mean that it isn't actually lazy, but for your release code you can build with CC in `ReleaseRequires` mode and these types of check will be eliminated (having a read in the manual of the different 'levels' of contract enforcement is highly recommended!)

Answer (score 3):

After you edited in your comment in the code I can answer your question, but I don't think I'm answering the exact question lurking in the shadows here, you be the judge.

The only way to know what the property *would* resolve to *if* you read from it, is to actually read from it, evaluating the expression you constructed the underlying `Lazy<T>` field with.

Now, what you *can* do, is to check the underlying field to ask if it has been evaluated.

You can, in other words, do this:

```
if (lazyBar.IsValueCreated)
    ....
```

Now, whether that will work with a contract I'm not sure, but the following thing should allow you to check:

```
Contract.Requires(!lazyBar.IsValueCreated || lazyBar.Value != null);
```

Since I am not an expert on contracts, I don't know if the above code will be turned into an expression tree and evaluated either way.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding code contracts--isn't the whole point to prove that outcome of calling code must fit certain criteria without executing it? I'm new to code contracts so I'm probably just making some silly misunderstanding, but I though that was the purpose of the static analyzer.

Comment: For example, if `(A == foo)` implies `(B == bar)`, and you prove that `(A == foo)`, the static analyzer will know that `(B == bar)` without evaluating it.

Comment: There is no way to prove what the outcome of calling code will be without calling it. You can add code contracts that guarantee that the code will crash if the outcome ever deviates from what was expected, but the *actual* outcome cannot be proven, this is the halting problem in disguise. Note, *again*, I'm talking in the general sense. You will have lots of cases where it *can* be proven, for *some specific code*. However, in this case, you're calling code through a delegate, code contracts in .NET won't be able to handle that.

Comment: How would you set up code contracts to prove that `A==foo` implies `B==bar`?

Comment: @Lasse: I think you're missing the point a bit here. CC isn't about proving portions of arbitrary code, but proving relations between the contracts on that code. CC lives in an ideal world where things like ThreadAbortException and other C# nuisances don't exist - it works solely on the contracts you give it :)

Comment: @Lasse: the same way as in logic: `x implies y` is `!x || y`, so `A != foo || B == bar`.

Answer (score 0):

This partly depends on the type that you're dealing.

For example, types that inherit from `ICollection` will not be itterated over in order to evaluate such methods as `Count()`.

In the case where ICollection is implimented, the `Count()` method is optimised to check the `Count` property.

If you simply want to check that your Lazy object has "something" inside I suggest using the `Any()` method available to us in the `System.Linq` namespace.

This will then only need to do a single `MoveNext` in the collection before being able to determine whether there is "anything" inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why this doesn't work (and it really doesn't):

public class Foo
{
    private readonly Lazy lazyBar;

```
public Foo()
{
    lazyBar = new Lazy<string>(() => someExpression);
    Contract.Ensures(!lazyBar.IsValueCreated);
}

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private static void Invariant()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(!lazyBar.IsValueCreated || lazyBar.Value != null);
    }

public void DoSomething()
{
    Contract.Assume(lazyBar.IsValueCreated);
    lazyBar.Value.AccessSomeMethod; //Here Code Contracts detect "Possibly calling a method on a null reference"

    ...
}
```

}

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13231582)

Comment: Sure it is a new question? Now it works for me, and it is a Lazy approach (I declared the invariant as static, and it was the cause it didn't work).